# How to print a stack trace on uncaught exceptions inside a Servant handler?

Tags: haskell, exception, stack-trace, servant

When I build my application with profiling information, uncaught exceptions result in a nice stack trace being printed to the console. For example:

```
CallStack (from -prof):
  Redacted.Booking.API.Callback.Parse.parseFromEnv (src/Redacted/Booking/API/Callback/Parse.hs:(38,1)-(40,93))
  Main.main.readCallbackUrl (app/Main.hs:(51,5)-(54,77))
  Control.Exception.Lifted.finally.\ (Control/Exception/Lifted.hs:(426,22)-(427,47))
  Control.Monad.Trans.Control.liftBaseWith (Control/Monad/Trans/Control.hs:627:66-86)
  Control.Monad.Trans.Control.control (Control/Monad/Trans/Control.hs:751:1-39)
  Control.Exception.Lifted.finally (Control/Exception/Lifted.hs:(425,1)-(427,47))
  Control.Logging.withStderrLogging (Control/Logging.hs:(165,1)-(169,24))
  Redacted.Logging.withStderrLogging (src/Redacted/Logging.hs:(26,1)-(31,40))
  Main.main (app/Main.hs:(37,1)-(54,77))
```

However, if an uncaught exception occurs inside a Servant handler, no stack trace is printed -- only the exception, e.g.:

```
Prelude.maximum: empty list
```

I’m building using Stack, with both library and executable profiling enabled, by having the following in my stack.yaml:

```
build:
  library-profiling: true
  executable-profiling: true
```

How can I print a stack trace for an uncaught exception that happens inside a Servant handler?

Comment: I think the external library has to be built with profiling enabled. It might help if you showed how you're building your application / library.

Comment: @chris-stryczynski I’ve updated the post with information about how I build. Also, I believe the issue is that Servant catches the exception and rethrows it — which it has to do in order to respond to the client with a 500 status code.